# CATCH ERROR: NOK: Transaction not found with hash: With codeSTACKr's NFT art generator

Tags: javascript, nft

I am trying to create a NFT Collection. But I am facing issues.

I am using https://github.com/codeSTACKr/create-10k-nft-collection

When I run `npm run get_contract`. I did fill up all the required stuff.
It gives me an error. Is this normal? because It has last around half an hour

```
CATCH ERROR: NOK: Transaction not found with hash: 0x1b64f4e4757a32e612d9cd10a573a5508f23d9201576374c006f2b405385e13a
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have more images than it will take time to deploy. So wait for some time and try again!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).